# Angular JS - Resolve dependencies of a custom function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function which takes a service as a parameter.

```
function CustomFunc(MyAngularService) {
}
```

This function is not in the context of angular. This is not registered as a service. Is there a way to get this function invoked and get the dependencies injected and get the result back? Maybe using some sort of angular DI service?

One approach I can think of is get the parameter names of the function using some method like [this](http://www.mattsnider.com/parsing-javascript-function-argument-names/) and then using the $injector service to resolve the dependencies and invoke the function with those dependencies. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call this custom function from inside a controller, service or directive by using the `$injector` service.

Here is an example.

```
function CustomFunc(MyAngularService) {
}

angular.controller('Foo',function($injector) {
    $injector.invoke(CustomFunc); // <-- will handle dependencies for you
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought on applying @ThinkingMedia's answer. You could convert your functions into Angular services all in one go if you prefer to use them through Angular's DI.

```
function fn1(foo) {
  console.log('fn1', foo);
}
function fn2(bar) {
  console.log('fn2', bar);
}
function fn3(foo) {
  console.log('fn3', foo);
}

// put the functions into an array and interate over them    
[fn1, fn2, fn3].forEach(function(fn) {
   // use the function's name (es6) as service name
   app.factory(fn.name, function($injector) {
     return $injector.invoke.bind($injector, fn);
   });
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function(fn1, fn2, fn3) {
  // called with services injected
  fn1();
  fn2();
  fn3();
});
```

[**Click here for live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7yhk8ju/)

#### Old Answer

You could wrap it with an Angular service.

```
function CustomFunc(MyAngularService) {
  //etc
}

app.factory('foo', function(MyAngularService) {
  return CustomFunc.bind(MyAngularService); // or however suits you
});
```

The solution @MichaelP.Bazos offered may suit you best if change the usage. I believe this is what you're wanting to do:

```
CustomFunc(angular.injector(['myApp']).get('SomeService'));
CustomFunc(angular.injector(['myApp']).get('AnotherService'));
```

But you can also cut down on the verbosity of that, and I think it would be best anyway to use the `$injector` service:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($injector) {
  CustomFunc($injector.get('SomeService'));
});
```

Comment: I want to resolve dependencies on the fly, so wrapping in factory for each and every function would not be a very ideal solution.

Comment: Using the injector in this way will resolve the service, not the custom function **using** the service.

Comment: Well Raathigesh has to answer that, but I personally don't read the question as such. I think ThinkingMedia is on the right track.

Comment: @Yoshi Ah, I was thinking reusing the same function and changing out the injected service, whereas it seems he wants to use a lot of functions that are basically Angular services not attached to Angular. You're right.

Comment: Thanks guys for the replies. $injector.invoke(CustomFunc) solution provided by ThinkingMedia suits my needs for now. I'm sure these solutions also will help me at some point to get things done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

From outside angular context, you could try this:

```
angular.injector(['myApp']).get('MyAngularService')
```

Assuming `MyAngularService` is a component of module named `myApp`.

Here **[is a demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1kv2kvm/)**